# Leaflet control buttons group

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, leaflet.draw

Leaflet controls are added vertically as following:

```
map.addControl(new L.NewMarkerControl());
map.addControl(new L.NewLineControl());
map.addControl(new L.NewPolygonControl());
map.addControl(new L.NewRectangleControl());
map.addControl(new L.NewCircleControl());
```

### [image]

I need the buttons to look like the Zoom buttons (Joined) .. and horizontally if possible like this:

[image]

I can't find anything on the subject online :(

I guess that the code should look something like this:

```
var controlsContainer = new L.NewControlsContainer()
controlsContainer.addTo(map);

controlsContainer.addControl(new L.NewMarkerControl());
controlsContainer.addControl(new L.NewLineControl());
controlsContainer.addControl(new L.NewPolygonControl());
controlsContainer.addControl(new L.NewRectangleControl());
controlsContainer.addControl(new L.NewCircleControl());
```

Demo here: [CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/mikila85/pen/egwPje)

Please help.

Comment: This plugin looks promising: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.toolbar

Comment: it seems perfectly fine with the leaflet.draw, but when i try to do the same with the leaflet.editable it says: Control is not a function. http://codepen.io/mikila85/pen/QpwPXm (changes at the end)